# Import TXT file and create new worksheet for each grouped table

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have combined several CSV files into one large text file. I need to import this text file into Excel and create a new sheet every time there is 2 blank rows in the text file.

Is there a macro that can do this?

Example.TXT file:

```
"Date","Country","Price",
"12/01/12","US","$4.99",
"12/02/12","US","$4.99",


"Date","Country","Price",
"12/01/13","US","$4.99",
"12/02/13","US","$4.99",


"Date","Country","Price",
"12/01/14","US","$4.99",
"12/02/14","US","$4.99",
```

Comment: I don't see your code. I just see data. Where's your existing macro?

Comment: Your CSV's are malformed and will produce an extra field off the right-hand side. And yes,' there a macro that can do this?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, none of you helped. So I just deleted the large text file and created a macro to import all the original csv's.

```
Sub LoadAllFilesPerSheet()
Dim idx As Integer
Dim fpath As String
Dim fname As String
idx = 0
fpath = "c:\foobar\"
fname = Dir(fpath & "*.csv")
While (Len(fname) > 0)
    idx = idx + 1
    Sheets("Sheet" & idx).Select
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _
      & fpath & fname, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "a" & idx
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ""
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        fname = Dir
    End With
Wend
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I prepared something similar a few weeks before and I entered some adjustments so I could work with your example. But remember that SO is not the website for requesting code.

What is below should work. But before you should import your CSV file to the worksheet so it would like that:

[image: None]

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim cell As Range
Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet
Set SourceWorksheet = ActiveSheet

Dim TempFirstRowNumber As Long: TempFirstRowNumber = 1

For Each cell In Intersect(SourceWorksheet.Range("A:A"), SourceWorksheet.UsedRange)
    If cell.Value = "" And cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
        Sheets.Add after:=ActiveSheet
        SourceWorksheet.Range("A" & TempFirstRowNumber & ":C" & (cell.Row - 1)).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

        TempFirstRowNumber = cell.Offset(2, 0).Row
    End If
Next cell

Sheets.Add after:=ActiveSheet
SourceWorksheet.Range("A" & TempFirstRowNumber & ":C" & (SourceWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an entire module code sheet. When you paste it into a new module code sheet in a new blank workbook, do not leave two `Option Explicit` lines at the top of the page.

```
Option Explicit

Sub split_Date_Tables()
    Dim rowCurr As Long, tbl As Long
    Dim tlc As String, pth As String, fn As String, pthfn As String
    Dim fnd As Range

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    'set up the application environment for speed (see Sub appTGGL below)
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    pth = Environ("TEMP")
    fn = "example.txt"
    pthfn = pth & Chr(92) & fn
    tlc = "Date"  'header text in the Top-Left-Corner of each table

    'get rid of everything but the first blank worksheet
    Do While Sheets.Count > 1
        Sheets(2).Delete
    Loop

    'Importing a TXT is a lot of code that largely means nothing but has to set paramteters.
    'Put it in its own sub
    Call importTXT(Worksheets(1), pthfn, "txtSource")

    With Worksheets(1)
        With .Columns(1)
            Set fnd = .Find(What:=tlc, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            after:=.Cells(Rows.Count), _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            Do While Not fnd Is Nothing
                rowCurr = fnd.Row
                tbl = tbl + 1
                On Error GoTo bm_New_Worksheet
                With Worksheets(Format(tbl, "\C\S\V\-\000"))
                    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
                    .Cells.Clear
                    fnd.CurrentRegion.Copy _
                        Destination:=.Cells(1, 1)
                End With
                Set fnd = .FindNext(after:=fnd)
                If rowCurr > fnd.Row Then Exit Do
            Loop
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        End With
        .Activate
    End With

    GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

bm_New_Worksheet:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        With Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            .Name = Format(tbl, "\C\S\V\-000")
        End With
        Resume
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    appTGGL

End Sub

Sub importTXT(ws As Worksheet, fn As String, nam As String)
    With ws
        'nuke all existing data on this worksheet in favour of hte new data
        .Cells.Clear
        'bring in the new data
        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fn, _
            Destination:=.Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = nam
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(3, 2, 1, 9)
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        'we do not need to save this Data Connection. Get rid of it
        .Parent.Connections(.Parent.Connections.Count).Delete
    End With
End Sub

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
End Sub
```

IMO, this is a pretty good framework that you can build upon and customize for your own purposes. To get it going for the first time, you will have to modify the string assignments near the beginning of the code. CSVs with different table layouts may have to have the actual import sub procedure modified.

Two points:

- Your sample CSV showed trailing commas. This would leave empty fields off the right side. I've discarded these fields from the import. e.g. xlSkipColumn = 9
- Your dates were ambiguous. I've guessed at a MDY format. Use the values found at [TextFileColumnDataTypes property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215749%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to adjust the field types for import.